# Changing Hugo version on Netlify build

Tags: hugo, netlify

There is a new (0.32 at this time) version of `Hugo` that has just been released.

It was asked in the community how to handle this situation to test out the new version on a Netlify build.

> What is the recommended course of action for Netlify users?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not setup a variable `HUGO_VERSION` on `Netlify` it defaults to version `0.17` of `HUGO`.

### Simple Setup:

To target your builds Netlify has a custom variables field in the online console for your site. This will be enough for simple sites that need to target **all** workflow builds.
[image]

### Workflow Setup

`Netlify` allows for a config file (`netlify.toml`) at the root of your build package path that will tell it what configurations to use and will overwrite any build environment variables you setup in the simple example above.

`netlify.toml` example for `Hugo`

```toml
    [build]
      publish = "public"
      command = "hugo"
    # build a preview of the site [hugo --buildFuture]
    [context.deploy-preview]
      command = "hugo --buildFuture"
    # The default version you use for production if you don't use context
    [build.environment]
      HUGO_VERSION = "0.29"
    # The version you use for production
    [context.production.environment]
      HUGO_VERSION = "0.29"
    # you can lock a version of hugo for a deploy preview
    [context.deploy-preview.environment]
      HUGO_VERSION = "0.32"
    # you can lock a version of hugo for a branch-deploy (other than previews)
    [context.branch-deploy.environment]
      HUGO_VERSION = "0.32"
```

#### Things to note:

- Have different versions for a branch deploy for testing a new version of Hugo
- Also target other environment variables that `Netlify` allows like `NODE_VERSION`
- Setup **custom** environment variables to target builds explained in [this writeup](https://www.adartasoftware.com/post/hugo-netlify-stop-search-bots/) that can be accessed from within your `Hugo` templates!
- Read about deploy contexts for `Netlify` [Here](https://www.netlify.com/docs/continuous-deployment/#deploy-contexts)

Comment: Thanks for this. I was using lower case for the variable key so that's why it didn't work for me.