# How to use the container Hugo version with One Click Netlify CMS example

Tags: hugo, netlify, netlify-cms

In the [Netlify CMS community](https://gitter.im/netlify/NetlifyCMS) chat, the question keeps coming up how to manage the Hugo version without a bin folder and executable.

The [one-click-hugo-cms](https://github.com/netlify-templates/one-click-hugo-cms) example is a deploy to generate a Hugo static site and use Netlify CMS to be able to add posts for the site.

**The Issue**: The site setup uses a bin folder to store the Hugo executable for simplicity, but the developer wants to use a different version of Hugo and keep it up to date without having to keep copying new executables to the Hugo bin folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bin folder for Hugo is **NOT required**. Netlify manages a Hugo version install in the container based on the environment variable (`HUGO_VERSION`) when there is a build.

Basically follow these steps:

- Remove the bin folder and executable out of the project
- Change the command to the bin path and call it globally
- Let Netlify know what version you want to use in the `netlify.toml`

#### Remove the bin path

Edit this line

```
const hugoBin = `./bin/hugo.${process.platform === "win32" ? "exe" : process.platform}`;
```

to be

```
const hugoBin = 'hugo';
```

#### `netlify.toml`

```
[build]
  command = "yarn build"
  publish = "dist"
[build.environment]
  YARN_VERSION = "1.3.2"
  HUGO_VERSION = "0.36.1"

[context.deploy-preview]
  command = "yarn build-preview"
```

***NOTES:***

- Make sure on your local development to have [Hugo installed in a global path location](http://gohugo.io/getting-started/installing/)
- Netlify installs Hugo version 0.17 by default, so use `HUGO_VERSION` to specify version
- [Optional way to manage Hugo versions explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045132/changing-hugo-version-on-netlify-build)
- [one-click-hugo-cms example repo without bin folder](https://github.com/talves/one-click-hugo-cms/)

Comment: Please help me to understand how to remove the bin folder?. Should I just skip while adding to git commit or to use set of command as given in the snippet above? M using a windows 10 machine.

Comment: Once you have the solution working. Remove it from the git repository, because the files are not needed any longer. Of course, you will need to follow the install docs for Hugo on Windows to make it work locally.