# Netlify deploy for Hugo starter fails with "spawn EACCES" error

Tags: hugo, netlify, netlify-cms

I have used the Netlify CMS [Hugo Site Starter](https://github.com/netlify-templates/one-click-hugo-cms) to set up a site and it worked fine.
Then I took the files from the repository that was created and moved them over to a new Git repository and created a new Netlify site based on that repository. 
Suddenly the deploy is giving me an error when it tries to start Hugo:

```
10:03:37 PM: Starting 'hugo'...
10:03:37 PM: [21:03:37]
10:03:37 PM: 'hugo' errored after 14 ms
10:03:37 PM: [21:03:37]
10:03:37 PM: Error: spawn EACCES
10:03:37 PM:     at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:313:11)
10:03:37 PM:     at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:508:9)
10:03:37 PM:     at buildSite (/opt/build/repo/gulpfile.babel.js:81:13)
10:03:37 PM:     at Gulp.<anonymous> (/opt/build/repo/gulpfile.babel.js:23:27)
10:03:37 PM:     at module.exports (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
10:03:37 PM:     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
10:03:37 PM:     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
10:03:37 PM:     at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
10:03:37 PM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
10:03:37 PM:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
```

I can't seem to find anything on the "spawn EACCES" error in the context of Netlify deployments.
Anyone got any ideas or maybe had this problem before?

**EDIT:** To clearify a bit:
When I clone the original [Hugo Site Starter](https://github.com/netlify-templates/one-click-hugo-cms) Git repository and use that to deploy, all works fine.
When I create a new Git repository, commit+push the exact same contents as the cloned repo and try to deploy that as site, Netlify returns the `spawn EACCES` error. 
I did a Winmerge to look for changes and the only changes are in the `.git` folder because I created a new repository (so it has only one commit instead of 200+); the code is 100% the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the bin folder from your repository and [follow this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999330/how-to-use-the-container-hugo-version-with-one-click-netlify-cms-example/48999331#48999331)

It will allow you to change Hugo versions as you upgrade your local Hugo version. There are arguments to keep Hugo in a bin folder, because it has a small footprint, but when hosting on Netlify, I do not see any reason to do so. The drawbacks for me trying to keep track of what version is in that bin folder and the issue you are having add to my reasons for not keeping an executable version in the repository.

You will need to run a local version of Hugo globally for development, but you can follow the Hugo docs on how to do this.